# How can I get rid of this error 'invalid host header?'

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, create-react-app, cloud9

I am attempting to run an app built with create-react-app in AWS cloud9. I have a client and a rails server, and I use foreman to run both, like this:

/client/package.json:

```
{
"name": "fidirect",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"proxy": "http://localhost:8081/",
"devDependencies": {
"enzyme": "2.4.1",
"react-addons-test-utils": "15.4.0",
"react-scripts": "0.8.5"
},
```

procfile:

```
web: cd client && npm start
api: bundle exec rails s -p 8081
```

lib/tasks/start.rake:

```
task :start do
 exec 'foreman start -p 8080'
end
```

When I run rake start and navigate to the page, all I see is "invalid host header" What does this mean? What can I do about it?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/779dad55465de81972ec72257c734e4afae17094/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#invalid-host-header-errors-after-configuring-proxy

Comment: Hmmm. I added the code in the .env.development.local file but still no luck. Seeing the same error on the page. Weird.